# Game loop collision detection performance

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

I'm working on a Windows 10 2D board game, that sometimes can generate a chain reaction, where 144 moving objects can collide with 36 non-moving objects. This is the "worst" possible situation.

Every moving game object is created by some non-moving game object. The non-moving game object "shoots" moving game objects, and something happens when they collide with other non-moving game object :)

I'm using storyboards for moving XAML objects (UserControls), and checking for collisions with game loop based on CompositionTarget.Rendering.

Everything works great at my PC, but problem occures when I'm trying to make this effect on phone.

My game loop looks like this:

```
foreach (var movingGameObject in GameCanvas.Children.OfType<MovingGameObect>())
        {
            if (movingGameObject.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
                CheckCollision(movingGameObject);
        }
```

CheckCollision method looks like this:

```
        var left = Canvas.GetLeft(movingGameObject);
        var top = Canvas.GetTop(movingGameObject);
        var right = left + movingGameObject.Width;
        var bottom = top + movingGameObject.Height;

        // If left Canvas - remove
        if (left <= 0 || right >= GameCanvas.ActualWidth || top <= 0 || bottom >= GameCanvas.ActualHeight)
        {
            RemoveMovingGameObject(movingGameObject);
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            // Since it can go 4 ways - I check if it moves up, down, right or left
            if (movingGameObject.Way == Way.Left)
            {

                for (/* this is being done max 5 times, I checked it. It gets every possible game object id that may be on the way of moving game object */)
                {
                    if (this._gameObjects[i].IntersectsWith(movingGameObject))
                    {
                        RemoveMovingGameObject(movingGameObject);
                        GameObjectHit(this._gameObjects[i], null);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (movingGameObject.Way == Way.Right)
            {
                //SAME HERE
            }
            // SAME FOR UP and DOWN
        }
```

The GameObjectHit method checks if non-moving game object has to shoot another moving game objects etc. So when this is very bad scenario, game loop iteration has to check for collision and sometimes produce  another moving object(s) and shoot it(them).

And IntersectsWith method:

```
        var x1 = Canvas.GetLeft(this);
        var y1 = Canvas.GetTop(this);
        var r1 = new Rect(x1, y1, this.ActualWidth, this.ActualHeight);

        var x2 = Canvas.GetLeft(mgo2);
        var y2 = Canvas.GetTop(mgo2);
        var r2 = new Rect(x2, y2, mgo2.ActualWidth, mgo2.ActualHeight);

        r1.Intersect(r2);

        if (!r1.IsEmpty)
            return true;
        else
            return false;`
```

Oh, almost forgot. What's happening on phone? Game loop is being called not enough times and it don't check for collisions fast enough (moving objects just fly through non-moving objects).

I tried everything I possibly can to tweek a performance. I know that Windows 10 Mobile is in beta version and it will be faster, but the gameloop is being called ~2 times a second when it gets hot, so that's not the system fault.

Comment: i think your problems are i the controls and not in the collision detection loop. Did you measure how long the loop takes to execute on a device? One tip: you call a lot of dependency properties and attached properties, eg `Canvas.GetLeft` or `Canvas.ActualWidth` try caching these values if your loop is too slow.

Comment: I chaned few dependency and attached properties, but I can't really delete "Canvas.GetLeft" and "Canvas.GetTop", because this object is constantly moving. I could calculate position based on how long it's storyboard is in progress but I doubt it would be faster. And changes in calling properties didn't increase speed unfortunetely...

Comment: how long does your game loop to execute? Use a `Stopwatch` to measure or use VS built in performance tools

Comment: And game loop takes 1-2ms to run when there is basically nothing to do, and up to even 400ms when there are many moving objects...
During this 400ms everything is in different positions and it can even miss some collisions...

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a good use-case for XAML. Have you looked at Win2D?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought :/
Will I be able to easily re-use my code with Win2D?

Answer (score 0):

For anybody struggling with this problem in the future:
YES - this was a XAML-based performance issue.

I re-wrote the code with MonoGame (XNA) and there is no problem. Everything works just fine even on low-budget Nokia Lumia 635:)

I did not try Win2D option, but suspect the result would be as good as it is with MonoGame.

Thanks everybody for replies.